# Reading one data from SQLite to Unity without where codition

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

How can I retrieve one data from `SQLite` not using where condition?

I want retrieve one row in `SQLite` not using where condition ?

Here is my code:

```
public void GetOneUsername()
{
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(Connection))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            string selectoneusername = "select * from user_data;

            dbCmd.CommandText = selectoneusername;

            using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    name.text = reader.GetString(1);
                }
                dbConnection.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem? you already have the code without where condition.

Comment: but i want to select specific row not using where condtion.... in the case of my query above..the last inserted data will display in the unity

Comment: which row do you want to select? the first row? the last row? how is the row you want to select different form other rows?

Comment: You will have to be more specific if you want precise help. You could filter the result in the `while` loop : `while (reader.Read()) { name.text = reader.GetString(1); 
if( reader.GetString(1).Equals( "John Doe" ) ) break ; }` If you want to select the n-th row : `int rowIndex = 0 ; while (reader.Read() && rowIndex++ != n) { name.text = reader.GetString(1); }`

Comment: Thankyou @Hellium It works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter the result yourself, without the `WHERE` SQL clause, you can do this when you loop through your data:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     // You can filter with another column
    if( reader.GetString(1).Equals( "John Doe" ) )
    {
        name.text = reader.GetString(1);
        break ;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can retrieve only the n-th row :

```
for( int rowIndex = 0 ; reader.Read() ; ++rowIndex )
{
    if( rowIndex == n )
    {
        name.text = reader.GetString(1);
        break ;
    }
}
```